# Securing/Encrypting embedded database in Delphi

Tags: performance, security, delphi, encryption, embedded-database

Which method do you suggest to efficiently secure your embedded database in Delphi applications?

Here are the methods I've tested:

1. Using [Molebox Pro](http://www.molebox.com/)

   - Pros - Fast, unpacking is not child's play, no additional task/coding
   - Cons - Database will be read-only, same drawbacks as exe compressors
2. Using [DISQLite3](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlite3/index)

   - Pros - Overcome Molebox's read-only issue
   - Cons - 50% or more performance fall on encrypting

So I'd like to know if you have used anything like this in your projects and if you satisfied with speed and encryption etc. Please share your techniques.

Comment: How is 'unpacking is not (a) child's play' a pro?

Comment: Every packed exe can be unpacked/cracked. Unpacking moleboxed application is far more tough than unpacking a "Thininstalled" app, which costs several thousand $$. Isn't this a benefit?

Comment: No, it's not a benefit. If it's secure and encrypted already anyway, making it hard to unpack from the EXE file is just extra work. Encryption and embedding are orthogonal features; you just happen to want both in one product. Difficulty in unembedding doesn't affect the difficulty of unencrypting.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that Molebox Pro leaves your DB read-only while DISQLite3 does not seems to be the deciding factor.  Likewise if the performance penalty on encrypting is the only con for DISQLite3, then it is irrelevant since Molebox Pro is read-only (thus no encrypting during operation).  It really comes down to your requirements.

If you are looking for other options then I would suggest checking out [ElevateDB or DBISAM](http://www.elevatesoft.com/prodinfo?action=list) from [ElevateSoft](http://www.elevatesoft.com/).  They are both embedded databases with built in encryption.  I've used DBISAM, but ElevateDB is their newer and preferred database.  Also check out [Advantage DB](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/advantagedatabaseserver) from [Sybase](http://www.sybase.com/), which is less embedded but also has encryption.

If you have other requirements that may impact your choice let me know!

Comment: I've used the encrypted DBSIAM effectively. You still have the usual issue with keys having to be in the software, but it will make it harder.

Comment: @mj2008.  You could use a secure hash for the password, which would be harder to find.